# highcharts - Solid Gauge with plot lines

Tags: highcharts

I want to be able to show extra information on a solid gauge in the form of a plot line. It doesnt work as I expected it to but I wasn't sure it would work at all.

I have added a plotLine to the gauge's y-axis like so.

```
Axis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 200,
            title: {
                text: 'Speed'
            },
            plotLines: [{ color: 'green', width: 1, value: 6, dashStyle: 'Dash' }]
        },
```

I have taken the solid gauge example from the highcharts website and edited it

http://jsfiddle.net/wjaq4da2/

Can this be modified to work or should I take a different approach?

Comment: How you would like it to work? You may add zIndex to your plotLine, maybe this will meet your requirements: http://jsfiddle.net/wjaq4da2/1/

Comment: What's your expected result? As I see it trying to draw a green line over a green gauge value won't really work well.

Comment: I want a line that passes through the gauge but not from a central point of the chart. Hopefully, it would travel through the gauge and stop shortly after exiting the gauge. The line doesn't have to be green.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add additional info through the labels of plot-lines.
Like in this example:

```
plotLines: [{ 
    color: 'green', 
    width: 1, 
    value: 6,
    zIndex:10,
    dashStyle: 'Dash',
    label: {
        text: 'Description',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        //textAlign: 'left',
         y: -5
    }
}]
```

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aabramya/wjaq4da2/21/

Answer (score 0):

You can render arc using `Renderer.arc()` and set `outerRadius` and `innerRadius` with the same value.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer.arc

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/1j504gsq/